# What sci-fi novel has a technology called "Plaax" and a character named "Gifon"?

Tags: story-identification

Sometime in the late 70's or early 80's I read a sci-fi novel, the title and author of which have completely escaped me. I have a vague recollection of the plot, which I will describe here but please note that:

1) I may not remember it 100% accurately

**And**

2) The description contains a **spoiler** of the novel's ending.

The story concerns two children who, while exploring, discover a cave guarded by some sort of supernatural creature. Discovering the creature to be only an apparition, they venture inside and discover a spacecraft. Inside the spacecraft are a sleeping man and woman. The woman awakes and tells the children that she has flown from somewhere far away, and that her spacecraft is powered by a strange substance called "Plaax", which in turn was discovered when aliens visited *her* home planet. She wishes to revive her husband/partner whose name is Gifon, as he is in some sort of stasis/hibernation.

Ultimately, the story concludes with Gifon being awoken and the couple depart in the spaceship, leaving the children behind on Earth. The novel concludes with the children concluding that the couple did not come from another planet, but from Earth's future (*"they came from the future!"* being (a paraphrasing of) the last line of the novel).

Does anybody recognize this novel, and know what its title and author might be?

Comment: sounds interesting hope we find out what it is :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The book is called *[The Mist Lizard](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10305534-the-mist-lizard)* and the author is Marc Alexander.

> Inside they had found comfortable couches on the transparent floor,
>   while in the upper part of the globe floated strangely shaped and
>   **coloured blocks of Plaax**

and

> 'Simon,' said Neerak quietly, '**Gifon and I have come to a decision**.
>   The Time Pyramid must remain secret. We shall disappear once we have
>   landed you safely.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it’s this book? For example, quote relevant parts of a plot summary?

Comment: @TheMightyTharg I believe this is the correct book, many thanks.
Ironically, for a long time I had thought that the book's title might be "The Mist Lizard" but declined to do a search because I was convinced that I;d gotten that title mixed up with another, different book I had read.